# Where can I find touch-up paint?

Tags: frames, paint

I need grey touch-up paint for the headtube on a 2014 Whyte T-129s. How can I find out which colour exactly to buy?

Comment: If you want an exact colour I reckon your best bet is to contact either Whyte themselves, or one of their dealers. They list their dealers on their web site, there are lots in the UK by the looks of things.

Comment: Terms to search on are paint code and RAL.

Comment: If you go to an auto part place you can often find paint in little bottles with a brush in the cap.  Even if the color match is not perfect, if you just touch up a scratch with the brush it's hardly noticeable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sum up some comments:

- Contact the dealer or manufacturer for a specific color code or name
- Search various paints based on a similar code
- Get some touch-up paint from an auto parts store and use that

I would add that if you just go with regular touch-up paint, to make sure the gloss level matches the bike (most bikes have a high-gloss clear coat to protect the finish).

Also reference automotive touch-up guides to get an idea of how to best apply any paint (surface prep, etc).

Answer (score 1):

A cheap source of touch up paint, especially for the more garish colors is nail polish. Use a clear coat on tip for maximum strength.